# Modify jQuery slider to start in different position

Tags: jquery, slider

I'm using a slider that I got from another SO post - the original fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mjaA3/332/). I'm still pretty new to jQuery.

I've figured out how to stop it from playing automatically, but I was wondering if there is a way to modify the code so that it starts on a different slide other than 1? I have received a request to start it on the 2nd slide without removing the first.

This isn't a plugin like WowSlider or anything like that, just got the code from an awesome person on this site.  Here is my jQuery and [here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/psaj9/) with everything.

```
            var thumbs = $('ul.thumbHolder li');var bigImgs = $('ul.imgHolder li');
            var mask = $('.imgHolder');
            var imgW = $('ul.imgHolder li').width();
            var speed = 300;

            thumbs.removeClass('selected').first().addClass('selected');

            thumbs.click(function () {
                var target = $(this).index();

                mask.animate({
                    'left': '-' + imgW * target + 'px'
                }, speed);


                thumbs.removeClass('selected');
                $(this).addClass('selected');
            });


            $('.Bleft').on('click', function () {
                var i = $('ul.thumbHolder li.selected').index();
                i--;

                $('ul.thumbHolder li.selected').removeClass('selected');
                thumbs.eq(i).addClass('selected');

                if (i === -1) {
                    mask.animate({
                        'left': '-' + imgW * $('ul.thumbHolder li').index() + 'px'
                    }, speed);
                } else {
                    mask.animate({
                        'left': '-' + imgW * i + 'px'
                    }, speed);
                }
                clearInterval(counter);
            });
            $('.Bright').on('click', function () {
                var i = $('ul.thumbHolder li.selected').index();
                i = i >= thumbs.length - 1 ? 0 : i + 1;

                $('ul.thumbHolder li.selected').removeClass('selected');
                thumbs.eq(i).addClass('selected');

                mask.animate({
                    'left': '-' + imgW * i + 'px'
                }, speed);
                clearInterval(counter);
            });
            var count = 0;
            var counter = window.setInterval(timer, 5000);

            function timer() {
                count = count + 0;
                if (count >= 0) {
                    count = 0;
                    return;
                }
                mask.animate({
                    'left': '-' + imgW * count + 'px'
                }, speed);
                thumbs.removeClass('selected');
                thumbs.eq(count).addClass('selected');
            }
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place this code below the line that reads `var counter = window.setInterval(timer, 5000);`

```
thumbs.removeClass('selected').eq(1).addClass('selected');// the 1 is the zero-index of the li tag (the li is the image holder)
mask.animate({
    'left': '-' + imgW * 1 + 'px'// the 1 is the zero-index of the li tag
}, 0);// will place image in correct position in 0 milliseconds = no animation at start
```

Comment: thanks, this worked for me! appreciate the comments too, helps to learn.

Answer (score 0):

For example if you want to start on 2nd slide you have to replace this:

```
thumbs.removeClass('selected').first().addClass('selected');
```

with this:

```
thumbs.removeClass('selected').eq(1).addClass('selected');
```

The trick is that you pick the position of element containing the picture from 1 to 5 by selecting "thumbs" == "$('ul.thumbHolder li');" selector. There are 5 li elements in this ul, so **function eq(x)** enables you to pick xnd element, though picture you want.

Comment: Thanks Dejv. I tried it on the fiddle example I put above, and it worked like a charm. However, on mine, it still loads the first slide intially. Then, when I hit the next button, it skips the 2nd slide and jumps to number three. I have hidden the thumbnails and filled the list items for the thumbnails with &nbsp;  could that have something to do with it?

Comment: I'm not quite sure, if I take your code and insert it into fiddle accessible throw link you provided and I make a change that I suggested everything works perfect as well. ... It might be necessary to provide me with full code so I can better test it.

Comment: I created a new fiddle with my current code - it has the fix you suggested but still starts on slide 1. i tried adding thumbnails and also adding back the auto-start function and it still doesn't go to slide 2. weird!  http://jsfiddle.net/psaj9/

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for posting your fiddle. I moved it to my localhost for better debugging options, but unfortunatelly I haven't been able to got it working. After fiddleling a little with your fiddle I got an idea: Why don't you simply reorganize your lis in your imgHolder ul? That way you can show them in any desired order. Also, for this to work correctly you want to switch eq(1) back to first() or eq(0).